# Why can this assumption be made about covers?

Tags: general-topology

I've been reading more into different types of covers. In particular, $\omega$-covers. Let $X$ be an infinite topological space. $\mathcal{W}$ is an $\omega$-cover of $X$ if it is a non-trivial cover of $X$ and each finite subset of $X$ is contained in some $W \in \mathcal{W}$.

I came across the following assumption when considering sequence of $\omega$-covers.

> Suppose $X$ has a sequence of open $\omega$-covers $\{\mathcal{W}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. We may assume $\mathcal{W}_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{W}_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here, a refinement of a cover $C$ of a topological space $X$ is a new cover $D$ of $X$ such that every set in $D$ is contained in some set in $C$.

I'm having trouble seeing why this assumption can be made and how one would show the refinement of an $\omega$-cover of $X$ would still be an $\omega$-cover of $X$. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a little more context to that assumption? It may just mean that if $\mathcal{W_{n+1}}$ does not cover $\mathcal{W}_n$, then you replace the former with the common refinement of the two.

Comment: @josh I think Kevin's point is that the "we may assume . . . " is specific to what the text is trying to *prove*. So, what is the goal of this argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$ be arbitrary open $\omega$-covers of $X$. Let $\mathscr{R}=\{U\cap V:U\in\mathscr{U}\text{ and }V\in\mathscr{V}\}\setminus\{\varnothing\}$; clearly $\mathscr{R}$ refines $\mathscr{U}$ and $\mathscr{V}$. Let $F$ be a finite subset of $X$. By hypothesis there are $U_F\in\mathscr{U}$ and $V_F\in\mathscr{V}$ such that $F\subseteq U_F$ and $F\subseteq V_F$, so $F\subseteq U_F\cap V_F\in\mathscr{R}$, and $\mathscr{R}$ is an open $\omega$-cover of $X$.

Given a family $\{\mathscr{W}_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of open $\omega$-covers of $X$, let $\mathscr{R}_0=\mathscr{W}_0$, and for $n>0$ let $\mathscr{R}_n$ be the joint refinement of $\mathscr{R}_{n-1}$ and $\mathscr{W}_n$ constructed above. Then $\langle\mathscr{R}_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a refining sequence of open $\omega$-covers of $X$ such that $\mathscr{R}_n$ refines $\mathscr{W}_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the context of the phrase 'As we can suppose...' more carefully.  I suspect this is one of those 'without loss of generality assume X' situations.  In this context, maybe it is the case that from an arbitrary sequence of covers one can always (or always within the current proof context!) derive another sequence of covers where each cover is a refinement of the last.  Then what is really being said is 'Let's assume that that has been done'.